# Toggle attr value on click

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to toggle a attr value (rel or href) on click.

```
$('#open').click(function () {
    $(this).text($(this).text() == 'View Project' ? 'Close' : 'View Project');
    $(this).attr('rel','#page');
    $('#view').slideToggle(550);
    return false;
});
```

I've got a text swap in there that's change out the text for a#open when toggled open/toggle close.

But I need to swap the **rel** or **href** from **#view** to **#page** when toggled open but then back to **#view** on the toggle close. I'm needing the swap of these as it's needed for using scrollTop.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you're wanting to do the same thing to your rel attribute that you're doing to the text of the element.

```
$(this).attr('rel',$(this).attr('rel') == '#page' ? '#open' : '#page');
```

and I assume you want to use the current rel for the slide toggle

```
$($(this).attr('rel')).slideToggle(550);
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure I understand completely, but have you considered using `.toggle()` in jquery in place of `.click()` and then use different functions

Comment: I had used toggle but it was not working well with the page scroll, which is based on setting rel or from the href ----

var element = $(this).attr('rel');
var destination = $(element).offset().top;
$('html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)').animate({ scrollTop: destination}, 550 );